# Python Polars efficiently enumerating Rows in new Column

Tags: python, bigdata, python-polars

I want to create a new Column in my DataFrame, that enumerates the rows in it. My DataFrame has a couple million elements in it, for this reason I need it to be processed in the Rust engine, so without using something like `apply()`

My DataFrame:

```
┌─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ foo ┆ N   ┆ bar │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ str ┆ i64 ┆ str │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ A   ┆ 1   ┆ k   │
│ A   ┆ 2   ┆ l   │
│ B   ┆ 2   ┆ m   │
│ B   ┆ 4   ┆ n   │
│ C   ┆ 2   ┆ o   │
└─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

expected output:

```
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ foo ┆ N   ┆ bar ┆ c   │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ str ┆ i64 ┆ str ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ A   ┆ 1   ┆ k   ┆ 1   │
│ A   ┆ 2   ┆ l   ┆ 2   │
│ B   ┆ 2   ┆ m   ┆ 3   │
│ B   ┆ 4   ┆ n   ┆ 4   │
│ C   ┆ 2   ┆ o   ┆ 5   │
└─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

Comment: Can't you do `pl.Series('c',values=range(#rows))` and assign that to the column?

Comment: [`.with_row_count()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.with_row_count.html#polars.DataFrame.with_row_count)